# How to Change Jupyter Notebook Theme from Light Mode to Dark Mode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to convert my Jupyter notebook into Dark Mode then i got this error below

**Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Users\DELL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
Please can anyone help me.....
I would love to convert my Jpt to Dark Mode

Trying to Change my Jupyter notebook  from Light Mode into Dark Mode (Theme)

Comment: Take a look at [How Can I Customize Jupyter Notebook Into Dark Mode](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-can-i-customize-jupyter-notebook-into-dark-mode-7985ce780f38)  for help.